# How do I get client_max_body_size (nginx - php-fpm) as a value in PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, upload

I have written a file uploader for a custom app that breaks the file up into chunks and sends it to the server via ajax.  The issue I have is that I can pull the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size using ini_get, however, I cannot seem to get the client_max_body_size that nginx uses to dole out the 413 errors; and the answer space is polluted with people trying to up the limit.  I want my software to detect and work around the limit (since it already chunks things so well).  How can I detect client_max_body_size (or any other potential limit values) as a value in php (ideally in a generic manner that doesn't require modifying nginx files, so that code is drop in ready for the public, but i'll take what I can get).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's not available as a PHP ini variable you could may need to run a command that dumps nginx config values [e.g. `exec('nginx -T')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832033/dump-conf-from-running-nginx-process) and grep/parse it for the value you want

Comment: I think you can only get PHP's `upload_max_filesize` unless you make a configuration change to nginx's conf file to pass that value in `$_SERVER` or similar, but it would not be helpful with your generic approach

Comment: exec doesn't seem like a good idea.  I get permission denied... If I have to go that far out of my way I guess I can see why everybody wants to up that limit... Thank you for the idea however.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most sensible thing to do then is to hard code it in the config so that people can target their environments to their limitations manually.  I was hoping there was a better *generic* solution, but I guess there is not.