# Get Nginx config variable value from PHP

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

In my Nginx server block I have:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 8M;
...
```

Is there a chance I can read this value safely from the level of PHP script without parsing the file?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52030921/231316), it doesn’t sound directly possible

Comment: You can pass any value to PHP from nginx config as `fastcgi_param <VARIABLE_NAME> <value>`, for example `fastcgi_param MAX_BODY "8M";` and then read it in a PHP script in a way of `$_SERVER['MAX_BODY']`