# get previous nginx configuration file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

on my server (os : ubuntu 16) I have update my nginx configuration file by mastake then save and close the file , Is there away to get previous file before changes , hint: I havn't restart nginx on my server yet . I need help immediately

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your version of nginx.

See here: [dump conf from running nginx process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832033/dump-conf-from-running-nginx-process)

in any case, you can [dump the original nginx config-file with gdb](https://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process).

Also, if you edited the file with a gnome software, there's a chance the config file backup is still there, under "filename~" (note the tilde at the end).

Or you can [get the old inode from /proc/pid/fd](https://serverfault.com/questions/45237/link-to-a-specific-inode) (Linux keeps old used files in memory, until all processes using them exited - since nginx still runs, the inode is still there - inode or index node is the id of the file on the file system).